# Не сохраняются данные после редактирования. php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, pdo

пишу для сайта облако тегов, столкнулся с проблемой:

После успешного добавления нового тега (данных в базу), этот тег не редактируется, то есть новые данные не сохраняются при редактировании, при этом в логах никаких ошибок не получаю.

Буду очень рад если подскажете где допущена ошибка!

**Здесь предоставлены лишь те методы, которые взаимодействуют между собой, для лучшего восприятия вопроса**

**Код с модели:**

```
    public static function getById($id)
    {
        $new = database::i()->tags('id = ?', $id)->fetch();

        return $new;
    }

    function updateNew($data) // обновление данных в базе
    {
        if(isset($data['title']) && trim($data['title']) != '')
            $this['title'] = $data['title'];

        if(isset($data['background']) && trim($data['background']) != '')
            $this['background'] = $data['background'];

        $this->update();
    }
```

**Код с контроллера:**

```
function save() // сохранение данных
    {
        $id = (isset($this->request['new_id'])) ? (int)$this->request['new_id'] : 0;

        $new = model_tag::getById($id);
        $data = $this->request;

        if($id > 0 && $new) // проверка есть ли такой id уже в базе (если есть обновляем его содержимое)
        {
            $new->updateNew($data);
        }
        else
        {
            model_tag::setNew($data);
        }

        header('Location: '.APP_URL.'tag');
        exit();
    }
```

**Код представления:**

```
<!-- Add Tag-->
<div class="row">
    <form action="{{ app }}tag/save" method="post">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 pull-left">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">Общая информация</div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="title">Название</label>
                        <input type="text" name="title" class="form-control" value="{{ new.title }}">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="title">Выберите цвет</label>
                        <span class="color-picker">
                          <label for="colorPicker">
                            <input type="color" name="background" value="" id="colorPicker">
                          </label>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Сохранить</button>
                        <a href="{{ app }}tag" class="btn btn-danger">Отмена</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>  
    </form>
</div>
<!-- List and Edit/Remove tags-->
<table class="table table-striped table-hover table-responsive table-valign">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Название</th>
            <th>Дата добавления</th>
            <th>Значение</th>
            <th>Цвет</th>
            <th width="1%">{{ t('actions') }}</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {% if list|length > 0 %}
            {% for item in list %}
                <tr>
                    <td><span class="badge badge-light label" style="background: {{ item.background }}">{{ item.title }}</span></td>
                    <td>{{ item.created_at|date("d.m.Y") }}</td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="hidden" name="new_id" value="{{ item.id }}">
                        <input type="text" name="title" class="form-control" value="{{ item.title }}" disabled>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="color" name="background" value="" id="colorPicker" disabled>
                    </td>
                    <td nowrap>
                        <a href="{{ app }}tag/edit/{{ item.id }}" class="btn btn-info btn-xs edit_tag" data="{{ item.id }}">{{ t('Редактировать') }}</a>
                        <a href="{{ app }}tag/remove/{{ item.id }}" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs">{{ t('Удалить') }}</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        {% else %}
            <tr>
                <td colspan="6" class="table-empty">
                    {{ t('Данных нет') }}
                </td>
            </tr>
        {% endif %}
    </tbody>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function() {
        $('.edit_tag').click(function() {
            event.preventDefault();

            var a = $(this);
            input = a.parent().prev().prev().find('input.form-control');
            background = a.parent().prev().find('input#colorPicker');
            input.removeAttr( "disabled" );
            background.removeAttr( "disabled" );
            var tag_id = a.attr('data');

            if(a.text() == 'Редактировать') {
                // 
            }

            if(a.text() == 'Сохранить') {
                console.log(input.val(), tag_id, frontend + '/admin/tag/save', background.val());
                $.post(frontend + '/admin/tag/save', {new_id: tag_id, title: input.val(), background: background.val()}, function() {

                    input.attr('disabled', 'true');
                    background.attr('disabled', 'true');
                    a.text('Редактировать');
                    return false;

                });
            }

            if(a.text() == 'Отменить') {
                input.attr('disabled', 'true');
                background.attr('disabled', 'true');
                a.text('Редактировать');
                return false;
            }

            a.text('Отменить');

            input.keypress(function() {
                a.text('Сохранить');
            });

            // color picker
            document.querySelectorAll('input[type=color]').forEach(function(picker) {
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

**Ответ на комментарий ниже по поводу метода update():**

```
/** Update all rows in result set
    * @param array ($column => $value)
    * @return int number of affected rows or false in case of an error
    */
    function update(array $data) {
        if ($this->notORM->freeze) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!$data) {
            return 0;
        }
        $values = array();
        $parameters = array();
        foreach ($data as $key => $val) {
            // doesn't use binding because $this->parameters can be filled by ? or :name
            $values[] = "$key = " . $this->quote($val);
            if ($val instanceof NotORM_Literal && $val->parameters) {
                $parameters = array_merge($parameters, $val->parameters);
            }
        }
        if ($this->parameters) {
            $parameters = array_merge($parameters, $this->parameters);
        }
        // joins in UPDATE are supported only in MySQL
        #var_dump( "UPDATE" . $this->topString($this->limit, $this->offset) . " $this->table SET " . implode(", ", $values) . $this->whereString(), $parameters );
        $return = $this->query("UPDATE" . $this->topString($this->limit, $this->offset) . " $this->table SET " . implode(", ", $values) . $this->whereString(), $parameters);
        if (!$return) {
            return false;
        }
        return $return->rowCount();
    }
```

Comment: Укажите хотя бы framework, который используете. 
Пока совсем не ясно, что за метод $this->update() и существует ли $this->request['new_id'].

Comment: Благодарю, что откликнулись, ответы на вопросы:

Comment: Фреймворк самописный,
Метод **$this->update()** это глобальный метод который доступный по всему приложению, он часть библиотеки NotORM, я прикреплю и выделю его в своем вопросе выше.
По поводу **$this->request['new_id']**, вар дамп выдает следующее: **string(2) "17"**, номер эквивалентен номеру id в базе данных, то есть данные есть.

Comment: А var_dump( "UPDATE" что выдаёт?

Comment: $this['title'] = $data['title']; на $this->title = $data['title'];?

Comment: И topString() покажите

Answer (score 0):

Смущает вот это

```
$return = $this->query("UPDATE" . $this->topString($this->limit, $this->offset) . " $this->table SET " . implode(", ", $values) . $this->whereString(), $parameters);
```

Если предположить, что `$this->topString($this->limit, $this->offset)` это LIMIT, то ему там не место. Да и ничему там не место.

```
"UPDATE table SET target_field = 'target_value' WHERE condition_field = 'condition_value'"
```

И эта запись только затрудняет отладку:

```
if (!$return) { //$this->query()
    return false;
}
```

Возвращать всё таки надо результат выполнения запроса.